# We have a Nighthawk modem/router compatible with Google nest router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

We have a Netgear c7000v2 modem/router combo and only internet service. IP approved said unit. We had an issue after 1 year. Suddenly we have intermittent service. IP tech said we were being hacked and had us disconnect wireless printer when not in use and disconnect the Netgear repeater we used( type used house wiring for extension). Recommended Google Nest H2D router + 2 points, and we bought these. Now can I connect to my r7000 router/modem? Or will it be conflict? Can I shut wifi off in Nighthawk? Slight impasse, needing help.

Comment: You still need the modem. Boy were you given some really expensive advice. Your router can’t act as your modem. So you’ll have to wireless or using a CAT6 cable connect the router to the modem.

Comment: My exhisting unit is Netgear Nighthawk 7000 modem/router all in one device and this is my problem moving forward. Can I just plug the Google Nest H2D router into it ? Can I turn off wifi in Nighthawk?